# Rewriting Final Variables on Button Click

Tags: java

I am stuck on a piece of homework. We are tasked with creating a hangman game that, when the start button is clicked, will create a select a word. When a button is clicked, it will search that character and return it. It also has a stop button that will end the game. If the Start Button is clicked again, it needs to grab a new word and thus a new string of blank spaces to choose from. As you can see below, I currently have a couple final variables so that they can be passed to the methods to search for characters. These values need to be overridden when the Start Button is clicked. Any way this is possible? I really just need a way to restart the game when the start button is clicked.

```
     package hangman;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.SystemColor;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JMenu;

public class HangmanGame {


    private JFrame frmHangman;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    HangmanGame window = new HangmanGame();
                    window.frmHangman.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public HangmanGame() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {


            String words[];

            words = new String[] {"SMALL", "HINGE", "ORTHODOX","EMPTY", "SOUTH", "SOCIAL",
            "AFTERSHOCK", "CROWN","GRIEVING", "NEBULA"};

            int randomNum;
            randomNum = 0 + (int)(Math.random()*10); 

            final String currentWord = words[randomNum];

            System.out.println(currentWord);

            final StringBuffer blanks;
            blanks = makeBlanks(currentWord);

            int tries = 0; 




        frmHangman = new JFrame();
        frmHangman.setTitle("Hangman");
        frmHangman.setBounds(100, 100, 506, 372);
        frmHangman.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmHangman.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        final JButton btnStop = new JButton("Start Game");
        btnStop.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        btnStop.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        btnStop.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        btnStop.setBounds(10, 269, 132, 30);
        frmHangman.getContentPane().add(btnStop);

        JLabel lblWelcome = new JLabel("WELCOME TO HANGMAN");
        lblWelcome.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblWelcome.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblWelcome.setBounds(74, 9, 329, 41);
        frmHangman.getContentPane().add(lblWelcome);

        final JLabel lblXXX = new JLabel("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        lblXXX.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
        lblXXX.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblXXX.setBounds(74, 73, 329, 30);
        frmHangman.getContentPane().add(lblXXX);

        JPanel firstRowKey = new JPanel();
        firstRowKey.setBounds(2, 113, 477, 33);
        frmHangman.getContentPane().add(firstRowKey);

        final JButton btnA = new JButton("A");
        btnA.setEnabled(false);
        firstRowKey.add(btnA);

        final  JButton btnB = new JButton("B");
        btnB.setEnabled(false);
        firstRowKey.add(btnB);

        final JButton btnC = new JButton("C");
        btnC.setEnabled(false);
        firstRowKey.add(btnC);

        final JButton btnD = new JButton("D");
        btnD.setEnabled(false);
        firstRowKey.add(btnD);

        final  JButton btnE = new JButton("E");
        btnE.setEnabled(false);
        firstRowKey.add(btnE);

        final  JButton btnF = new JButton("F");
        btnF.setEnabled(false);
        firstRowKey.add(btnF);

        final JButton btnG = new JButton("G");
        btnG.setEnabled(false);
        firstRowKey.add(btnG);

        final  JButton btnH = new JButton("H");
        btnH.setEnabled(false);
        firstRowKey.add(btnH);

        final JButton btnI = new JButton("I");
        btnI.setEnabled(false);
        firstRowKey.add(btnI);

        final  JButton btnJ = new JButton("J");
        btnJ.setEnabled(false);
        firstRowKey.add(btnJ);

        JPanel secondRowKey = new JPanel();
        secondRowKey.setBounds(0, 146, 479, 33);
        frmHangman.getContentPane().add(secondRowKey);

        final JButton btnK = new JButton("K");
        btnK.setEnabled(false);
        secondRowKey.add(btnK);
        btnK.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

        final  JButton btnL = new JButton("L");
        btnL.setEnabled(false);
        secondRowKey.add(btnL);
        btnL.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

        final  JButton btnM = new JButton("M");
        btnM.setEnabled(false);
        secondRowKey.add(btnM);
        btnM.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

        final JButton btnN = new JButton("N");
        btnN.setEnabled(false);
        secondRowKey.add(btnN);
        btnN.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

        final JButton btnO = new JButton("O");
        btnO.setEnabled(false);
        secondRowKey.add(btnO);
        btnO.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

        final JButton btnP = new JButton("P");
        btnP.setEnabled(false);
        secondRowKey.add(btnP);
        btnP.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

        final JButton btnQ = new JButton("Q");
        btnQ.setEnabled(false);
        secondRowKey.add(btnQ);
        btnQ.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

        final JButton btnR = new JButton("R");
        btnR.setEnabled(false);
        secondRowKey.add(btnR);
        btnR.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

        final  JButton btnS = new JButton("S");
        btnS.setEnabled(false);
        secondRowKey.add(btnS);
        btnS.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

        final JButton btnT = new JButton("T");
        btnT.setEnabled(false);
        secondRowKey.add(btnT);
        btnT.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

        JPanel thirdRowKey = new JPanel();
        thirdRowKey.setBounds(0, 181, 479, 41);
        frmHangman.getContentPane().add(thirdRowKey);

        final JButton btnU = new JButton("U");
        btnU.setEnabled(false);
        thirdRowKey.add(btnU);
        btnU.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

        final  JButton btnV = new JButton("V");
        btnV.setEnabled(false);
        thirdRowKey.add(btnV);
        btnV.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

        final JButton btnW = new JButton("W");
        btnW.setEnabled(false);
        thirdRowKey.add(btnW);
        btnW.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

        final JButton btnX = new JButton("X");
        btnX.setEnabled(false);
        thirdRowKey.add(btnX);
        btnX.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

        final JButton btnY = new JButton("Y");
        btnY.setEnabled(false);
        thirdRowKey.add(btnY);
        btnY.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

        final JButton btnZ = new JButton("Z");
        btnZ.setEnabled(false);
        thirdRowKey.add(btnZ);
        btnZ.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

        final JPanel panelTries = new JPanel();
        panelTries.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panelTries.setBounds(0, 0, 101, 62);
        frmHangman.getContentPane().add(panelTries);
        panelTries.setVisible(false);

        final JLabel lblNumberTries = new JLabel(Integer.toString(tries));
        panelTries.add(lblNumberTries);
        lblNumberTries.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblNumberTries.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblNumberTries.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblNumberTries.setVisible(false);

        final JLabel lblTries = new JLabel ("Tries");
        panelTries.add(lblTries);
        lblTries.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblTries.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        lblTries.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblTries.setVisible(false);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frmHangman.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(mnFile);

        JMenu mnHelp = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(mnHelp);




        btnA.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'A');
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnB.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'B');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnC.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'C');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnD.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'D');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnE.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {


                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'E');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnF.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'F');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnG.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'G');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnH.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'H');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnI.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'I');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnJ.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'J');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnK.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'K');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnL.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'L');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnM.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'M');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnN.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'N');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnO.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'O');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnP.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'P');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnQ.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'Q');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnR.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'R');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnS.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'S');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnT.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'T');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnU.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'U');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnV.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'V');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnW.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'W');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnX.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'X');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnY.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'Y');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });
        btnZ.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, 'Z');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                int counter = counterUpdate(Integer.parseInt(lblNumberTries.getText()));
                lblNumberTries.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });

        btnStop.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            if (lblXXX.getText() == "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"){
                StringBuffer blanks = makeBlanks(currentWord);
                String displayText =matchLetter(currentWord, blanks, '-');  
                lblXXX.setText(displayText);
                lblTries.setVisible(true);
                lblNumberTries.setVisible(true);
                panelTries.setVisible(true);
                btnStop.setText("Stop Game");
                btnA.setEnabled(true);
                btnB.setEnabled(true);
                btnC.setEnabled(true);
                btnD.setEnabled(true);
                btnE.setEnabled(true);
                btnF.setEnabled(true);
                btnG.setEnabled(true);
                btnH.setEnabled(true);
                btnI.setEnabled(true);
                btnJ.setEnabled(true);
                btnK.setEnabled(true);
                btnL.setEnabled(true);
                btnM.setEnabled(true);
                btnN.setEnabled(true);
                btnO.setEnabled(true);
                btnP.setEnabled(true);
                btnQ.setEnabled(true);
                btnR.setEnabled(true);
                btnS.setEnabled(true);
                btnT.setEnabled(true);
                btnU.setEnabled(true);
                btnV.setEnabled(true);
                btnW.setEnabled(true);
                btnX.setEnabled(true);
                btnY.setEnabled(true);
                btnZ.setEnabled(true);

            }
            else{
                lblXXX.setText("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                lblTries.setVisible(false);
                btnStop.setText("Start Game");
                lblNumberTries.setVisible(false);
                panelTries.setVisible(false);
                lblNumberTries.setText("0");
                btnA.setEnabled(false);
                btnB.setEnabled(false);
                btnC.setEnabled(false);
                btnD.setEnabled(false);
                btnE.setEnabled(false);
                btnF.setEnabled(false);
                btnG.setEnabled(false);
                btnH.setEnabled(false);
                btnI.setEnabled(false);
                btnJ.setEnabled(false);
                btnK.setEnabled(false);
                btnL.setEnabled(false);
                btnM.setEnabled(false);
                btnN.setEnabled(false);
                btnO.setEnabled(false);
                btnP.setEnabled(false);
                btnQ.setEnabled(false);
                btnR.setEnabled(false);
                btnS.setEnabled(false);
                btnT.setEnabled(false);
                btnU.setEnabled(false);
                btnV.setEnabled(false);
                btnW.setEnabled(false);
                btnX.setEnabled(false);
                btnY.setEnabled(false);
                btnZ.setEnabled(false);
            }

            }
        });

    }

    public static StringBuffer makeBlanks(String s)
   {
      StringBuffer blanks = new StringBuffer(s.length());
      for (int count=0; count < s.length(); count++)
         blanks.append('-');
      return blanks;
   }


   public static String matchLetter(String currentWord, StringBuffer blanks, char searchChar)
    {
       String newBlanks;
       String thisCurrentWord = currentWord;

      if(searchChar=='-'){
          newBlanks = makeBlanks(thisCurrentWord).toString();
          }

       for (int index = 0; index < thisCurrentWord.length(); index++)
          if (thisCurrentWord.charAt(index) == searchChar)
             blanks.setCharAt(index, searchChar);
       newBlanks = blanks.toString();
       return newBlanks;


    }   
   public static int counterUpdate(int currentNumber)
   {
       currentNumber += 1;
       return currentNumber;

   }

}
```

Comment: What do you think `final` means?

Comment: `"As you can see below, I currently have a couple final variables so that they can be passed to the methods to search for characters. These values need to be overridden when the Start Button is clicked. Any way this is possible?"` -- don't make them final, and instead make them instance fields.

Comment: So much needless redundancy -- please do yourself a favor and eliminate that as doing so will make debugging and improving this program so much easier for you and for us.

Comment: I was almost sure it meant that it could not be overridden, but I heard that it could be. I am just not sure how it would be done within the context of my code.

Comment: `"I am just not sure how it would be done within the context of my code."` -- I thought that I had already addressed this in my comment above. Again, use instance fields instead of local final variables if you need to pass information into an inner class.

Comment: In Java, the `final` keyword denotes a field/variable/object/etc. that can't be reassigned. That is, once you set the variable equal to something, you won't be able to change it.

Comment: I apologize. I saw your second comment first. I am picking up java for the first time in years. I am looking into making them instance fields.

Comment: So if I wanted to change "currentWord" to an instance field that I can pass into methods, how would that look? Currently it looks like "final String currentWord = words[randomNum];"

Comment: I suppose, you should learn a bit more about [Object-Oriented Programming](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/).

Btw. storing your buttons in some kind of collection - [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for example would make the code look way more convenient. You could also assign listeners to those buttons in the loop then. The listeners can determine what letter should be used basing on the button's text.